# ValidateFormDigest - when exactly does it need to be called?

Tags: security, impersonation, unsafe-updates

Can someone explain to me exactly when and why I need to call `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest`?

Contrary to [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.validateformdigest.aspx), which says you need to call it before elevating privileges, I've had the following work:

1. Elevate permissions
2. Call `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()`
3. Create sub web
4. Add user to group on web

Then I had the the following fail (complaining that the form digest is invalid)

1. Elevate permissions
2. Read elevated web''s `Url` property
3. Call `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest()`
4. Create sub web
5. Add user to group on web

but only at the point where I try to add the user to the group, *not* the point where I create the sub web!

I'd *expect*, if I've somehow invalidated the digest by *reading a property from a web* (honestly, SharePoint?), that either the *explicit validate call* would fail or the *first change I try to make* would fail, not the *second*. It leads me to believe that, if someone was genuinely attacking my site, they might be able to create subwebs even if they can't add people to groups.

I can fix the issue by moving the `Validate` call to before reading the `Url` property - again, contrary to the spec.

Comment: Both examples are executed on a POST request right? I can only assume that for some reason you are already starting with AllowUnsafeUpdate == true so you first test pass. Then in the second example reading the web url prop somehow calls a SPWeb.Invalidate, so the prop is reset. This is only a wild guess though.

Comment: I'm not setting `AllowUnsafe` anywhere in my code, and IIRC it's not something that's persisted past the lifetime of the `SPWeb` instance, so I don't think that can be it. both examples are executed identically, on a POST.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you why http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is updating content in SharePoint, then it is better to impersonate the system account instead of elevating privilege.

http://www.schaeflein.net/impersonation-and-elevation-of-privilege/

Also, even though your first scenario happens to work, you should validate the token before creating the new SPSite context.

Comment: I am elevating to an account, but it's not the system account. (I edited my question down to make it more succinct, apparently I edited that bit out...) I am now validating before opening the site, I just wish what's gonig on was a bit more transparent :(

Answer (score -5):

you need to use

```
Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates to true .
```

instead of messing with the digest.

from my experience

Also there might be a difference if your code running inside a webpart , page or an event handler.

give it a shot.

don't forget to revert to back to false when done

Best of luck.

Comment: `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is orthogonal to elevation - it allows you to make changes on a `GET` instead of a `POST`, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true

is something you'd need to do in rare cases only if you are  100% that it is necessary.